# Click an A link and open multiple new windows that go to different URLs?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I am doing a web site for someone who swears the way his old site worked was that when a user clicked on a specific link, the link would open up multiple browser windows with each going to a different destination.

Specifically, the link would say something like "compare prices" and clicking the link would open up a new window for Amazon.com, Bargains.com, and Overstock.com.

I do not believe I have ever seen this done without the use of JavaScript, like porn sites used to do (and maybe they still do but I don't visit them).  And didn't most browsers implement measures to stop multiple windows from opening at once?

Can you tell me whether this can be done and should it be done?

Comment: Am i right in thinking that everyone who answers this question is going to get voted down. FFS.

Comment: Wow, why would people get voted down for answering the question correctly?

Comment: "I do not believe I have ever seen this done without the use of JavaScript" OP, obviously knows of JS solutions.

Comment: Because this is a bad way to code a website, it is used for spamming, spreading viruses/links to porn or whatever. Why would you _EVER_ want to open several pages with one click? A user-click should always only do what's expected by the user.

Comment: Uh, that was question: how to do it and why (or not) to do it. The answer was perfectly appropriate. You shouldn't vote down a correct answer, if you did vote it down.

Comment: I think it would be better to just display multiple links with target="_blank" and then tell the user to click them. The way you want to do it will be blocked by popup blockers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=72649 This not also has the answers to your question but also good opinions on why its not great to have this action in place :)

Comment: I told my client that it was a really bad idea. First, it's annoying as hell. Second, it's really annoying. Third, I'm pretty sure that search engines frown on it because it's so heavily associated with porn.

Comment: Ha, indeed. I'd advise against it, go on the usability point of view.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it client-side:

```
$('#link-id').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://www.google.com');
    window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');
    window.open('http://www.msn.com');
});
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bPU3e/).